# how to design panel from tabbedpane and make panel to center

Tags: java, jframe, jpanel, jtabbedpane

[i want to make a bigger resolution/fullscreen but i dont know what layout should i use, can u guys help me to choose a better layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y5Y2Q.jpg)
this is the first code for first pic

```
    tp = new JTabbedPane();
    tp.setBounds(0,0,250,400);
    panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(250, 480));
    tp.addTab("Mahasiswa",panel);
    panel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    label_insert = new JLabel("NIM :               ");
    label_insert2 = new JLabel("ID Jurusan :   ");
    tf_insert1 = new JTextField(15);
    tf_insert2 = new JTextField(15);
    Insert = new JButton(" Insert ");
    //panel add
```

[this one i want to make it on middle of frame and all of them already on panel, how can i move it to the middle ?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mBzTR.jpg)
this is code for the second picture

```
    public void mainform(){

    main = new JPanel();
    main.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));
    label_main = new JLabel("ID");
    label_main2 = new JLabel("Password");
    tf_main = new JTextField(15);
    tf_main2 = new JPasswordField(15);
    login = new JButton("LOGIN");
    login.addActionListener(this);
    main.add(label_main);
    main.add(tf_main);
    main.add(label_main2);
```

Comment: Startby having a look at [Laying Out Components Within a Container](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) and consider using a more flexible layout, something like [How to Use GridBagLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html) for example

Comment: i dont think to use GridBagLayout cause the label and button is too large

Comment: You can apply padding to components via GridBagLayout which will effect their size

Comment: can u give me example about padding ? i dont know padding :(

Comment: I thinking you're mixing up `GridLayout` and `GridBagLayout`

Answer (score 0):

[Following this guide here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) I would suggest the following:

```
yourFrame = new JFrame();
yourFrame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

tp = new JTabbedPane();
yourFrame.add(tp, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

Then fiddle with GridLayout, GridBagLayout, or GroupLayout for the tabs in your tabbedpane.

Comment: but if i use like that, the tabbedpane is going to be center, but how about the panel, isnt Gridlayout have a large button or label ??

Answer (score 0):

I would consider using a `GridBagLayout` which will give you greater flexibility in how the components are laid out

[image: Layout]

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        public TestPane() {
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridy = 0;
            gbc.insets = new Insets(2, 2, 2, 2);

            add(new JLabel("ID"), gbc);
            gbc.gridx++;
            add(new JTextField(20), gbc);
            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridy++;
            add(new JLabel("Password"), gbc);
            gbc.gridx++;
            add(new JTextField(20), gbc);
            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridy++;
            gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
            gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
            add(new JButton("Login"), gbc);
        }

    }

}
```

See [Laying Out Components Within a Container](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) and [How to Use GridBagLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html) for more details

Comment: how to make it on top dude ?
all of them on the middle